# Is it possible to use Magento only for cart, purchase and order management and not for storing product catalog?

Tags: api, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, place-order, integration

We are exploring the possibility of a solution where we would not store any products in Magento, but instead, all products would be stored in a third-party application and exposed through an API. Magento would then be used solely for Cart management, Cart Price Rules, Customer Management, and Order Management.

I was wondering if such a solution is feasible, and if so, what steps would need to be taken to implement it successfully.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards